# Combobox INotifyPropertyChanged event not raised!

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-3.0, inotifypropertychanged

I created a combobox and set observable collection as the itemsource and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on the observable collection item. Even after that, when I select different item in the combobox, the OnPropertyChange method is not invoked. I think I am not making the binding properly. Could  any one please correct me/ suggest me in this regard.

---------------------------------MainPage.xaml---------------------------------------------------

```
<UserControl xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"  x:Class="MasterDetailsUpdate.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">

    <StackPanel Width="300">

            <ComboBox Name="cboName"></ComboBox>

            <TextBox Name="tbxName" Text="{Binding Path=name,Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=cboName}" ></TextBox>


    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

---------------------------MainPage.xaml.cs-----------------------------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MasterDetailsUpdate
{

    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            persons.Add(new Person { city = "c1", name = "n1" });
            persons.Add(new Person { city = "c2", name = "n2" });
            persons.Add(new Person { city = "c3", name = "" });
            persons.Add(new Person { city = "c4", name = "" });
            persons.Add(new Person { city = "c5", name = "n1" });

            cboName.ItemsSource = persons;
            cboName.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
        }       
    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _city;
        public string name
        {
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("name");
            }
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
        }


        public string city
        {
            set
            {
                _city = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("city");
            }
            get
            {
                return _city;
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

---

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 1):

No you aren't binding right, your textbox binding should look like this:-

```
<TextBox Name="tbxName" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.name, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=cboName}" />
```

A ComboBox doesn't have a `name` property.  It does have a `SelectedItem` property which will be the `Person` instance currently selected.  You then want the `name` property of that instance.  Hence the path you need in the binding is `SelectedItem.name`.

Now you should find that when you edit the textbox **and** move the focus elsewhere then PropertyChange event will fire and you should see the change in the combo box.

Note by default textbox does not update its value until the user presses tab or in some other way moves the focus on.